Keycloak 26.0.1 Multi-Domain Setup Not Working in Kubernetes Cluster
We are running Keycloak 26.0.1 in our Kubernetes cluster and are facing issues with a previously functional multi-domain setup. Here’s our configuration:

Domain login.example1.com routes to realm example1
Domain login.example2.com routes to realm example2

This setup worked perfectly in earlier versions of Keycloak. However, after upgrading, it no longer functions as expected.
We are using the following Helm chart from Bitnami: Bitnami Keycloak Chart 24.0.1 (https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/keycloak/24.0.1/bitnami/keycloak)
Steps Taken:
We've tried various combinations of the values in the Helm chart to resolve the issue, including:

keycloak.ingress.hostnameStrict: false
keycloak.proxyHeaders: forwarded

Unfortunately, none of these combinations have worked for us.
Question:
Has anyone experienced similar issues after upgrading to Keycloak 26.0.1, or does anyone know how to correctly configure multi-domain support in this version? We would greatly appreciate any input or guidance to help get this setup working again.
Thanks in advance!

If you success, let me know, we are in the same situation, cluster was all fine with previous versions, but since the 26th, when 2 nodes are running together, users' connection dos not work anymore. When I cut one node, it works perfectly. It seems problem comes from cache sessions with the new feature 'persistent-user-sessions', but we wan't figure it out

Hi Adrien, we got it working. We did not experience any issue with user connection.

Thanks for your return, can you tell me what you change for make it work ? I'm still stucked

It the past we had http traffic from ingress to the keycloak running in the pods. We changed it to https and it worked as a charm.
